# python snowflake udf that accesses data in snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let us say that I create a python udf like so:

```
create or replace function addone(i int)
returns int
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'addone_py'
as
$$
def addone_py(i):
  return i+1
$$;
```

Can I access data from a table + schema of where this udf is deployed - ideally whilst using a non default python package? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - can you give an example result that you are looking for?

Comment: It is quite hard to provide a reproducible example I reckon. So let us say we have a db X with a schema Y and a table T and a column C1 in snowflake. How can I add up all values in C1 in the Python function without passing them as parameters - i.e. access the data inside Python ... hope this makes more sense?

Comment: I'm sorry - if we can't reproduce, we can't fix. Please consider giving us some code so we can give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why everyone is asking code example. The question is clear. The answer is no, you cannot access a table from python udf. You would need to implement it as a stored procedure, which comes with another limitation: it cannot be called in a select statement

Comment: Thanks for you kind words - guess this is why everyone uses chatgpt these days (-: